# Questions about Merchant Center and payments from in-app purchases

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play, payment, merchant-account

I have few questions about Merchant Center ( payments.google.com )

I have few apps on the Google play store. In those apps people can make in-app purchases.

1. Is there a minimum amount of money that I need to achieve if I want to make a bank transfer and get those money? For example can I get 5$ from it or I have to wait until I get 100$.

2.How long time usually it takes to have this money in a bank account?

3.Are those payments are automatic or should I push a button ( or something like that) to start transfer process?

4.Can I print invoice for that money transfer ?

5.On that invoice there is one cumulative position for all payments or there is every single payment on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) In Merchant Center you can configure the Payment schedule, under Payment Settings in Payments section. Here you can choose the minimum payment threshold to make a bank transfer and get money. However the transfer are executed monthly.

2) When you are eligible for receiving a payment, money will be on your bank account in few days.

3) The payments are automatic, monthly, if your earnings exceed your payment threshold specified in 1).

4) and 5) I haven't found yet a regular invoice for transfers, but when a payment is executed you can print a simple Payment Receipt.